# determinant of sum of anticommuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB=-BA$ and $det(A)=0$ and $det(A+B)=0.$
Prove that $det(A^3+B^3)=0$.

I don't really know how to approach this question.

Comment: Please provide more context.  Where did you encounter this problem?  For example, in which chapter of which text is this presented? This gives a good hint as to which "trick" should be used here.  Do you have any thoughts of your own on how you expect the solution to go?

Comment: I just stumbled across it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need $AB=-BA$ and $\det(A+B)=0$, not $\det A=0$, to prove that $\det(A^3+B^3)=0$. The reason is that $A^3+B^3$ can be factored such that $A+B$ is a factor.

Using $BA=-AB$ and always normalising products to the form $A^pB^q$, i.e. all $A$ factors before all $B$ factors, the product
$$
(A+rB)(A+B)(A+sB)=A^3+(r+s-1)A^2B+(r+s-rs)AB^2+rsB^3 
$$
which equals to $A^3+B^3$ if $rs=1$ and $r+s=1$. This happens if $(r,s)=(z,\bar z)$ where $z=e^{\pm\pi i/3}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, so you get
$$
A^3+B^3=(A+zB)(A+B)(A+\bar zB)
$$
and therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\det(A^3+B^3)&=\det[(A+zB)(A+B)(A+\bar zB)]\\
&=\det(A+zB)\,\det(A+B)\,\det(A+\bar zB)=0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: And somewhat more generally, if $BA = \alpha A B$ for scalar $\alpha \ne 0$, then $$A^3 + B^3 = (A + r B)(A + B) (A + s B)$$ where $r = \omega/\alpha$, $s = -\alpha \omega - \alpha$, if $\omega$ is a root of $z^2 + z + 1$.  In particular $\det(A+B) = 0$ implies $\det(A^3 + B^3) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

That's false. Take $A$ be the $0$ matrix, and $B$ the identity matrix.

Comment: I edited it. I think now it works.